# Were those real helicopters in Kong Skull island?

Tags: props, kong-skull-island, monsterverse

Do we know for sure if the helicopters in *Kong: Skull Island* were real or CGI or both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems to be a combination of real, dummy (partial) and CGI creations as would be expected

> In a scene near the start of Kong: Skull Island, a band of adventurers buzzing around in military helicopters comes face-to-face with the monster that gives the film its title.
>
> A spectacular vertigo-inducing battle ensues between Kong and the copters.
>
> **Much of that scene was done at Industrial Light & Magic (ILM) Singapore.** Visual effects supervisor Jeff Capogreco, 41, says the scene "introduces us to Kong and he isn't very happy. People are invading his home".
>
> Real actors inside dummy aircraft whirl around digitally created Kong, with the fight taking place against jungle scenery and sky which might also be painted in by computer.
>
> "Singapore did the **helicopters being smashed and crushed**. Kong is roaring and jumping," says Mr Capogreco, who has worked here since 2014.
>
> <sup>[Source](http://www.straitstimes.com/lifestyle/singapore-connection-team-behind-visual-effects-for-kong-skull-island)</sup>

For crashes on the ground it seems that used dummy helicoper partials.. as can be seen here (c.50s)

Helicopters are **expensive**, much more expensive than having a VFX team put one together (especially as these are common items in movies and would be prety much "off the shelf") and using multiple CGI duplicates.